# Auto-shrinking ImageView

Tags: android, layout, imageview, scale

I'm currently trying to achieve the following:

I want to place an ImageView on the top of my Activity and a Button on the bottom (so far easy, right?). In-between there are three TextViews contained in a LinearLayout (vertical), which is centered in the Activity.

The effect I want to achieve is that as long as there is enough space on the screen, the image on top should scale to fill the screen width and otherwise (i.e., in landscape orientation) should scale down in order to make room for the LinearLayout and the Button.

My current setup allows the ImageView to fill the screen, but it overlaps with the LinearLayout once the phone is rotated (resulting in too little space above the LinearLayout). If I try to add `android:layout_above="@+id/linearlayout1"` to my ImageView it's not visible at all.

Here's my current layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:paddingTop="16dp"
android:paddingBottom="16dp"
android:background="#ff1e2c3d">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:tag="logo_view"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/linearlayout1"
        android:layout_above="@+id/continueButton">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Welcome!"
            android:id="@+id/ptcTextView"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/space"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:singleLine="false" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="There's some text here."
            android:id="@+id/progressTextView"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/space"
            android:singleLine="false" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="And even more here."
            android:id="@+id/uploadProgressTextView"
            android:tag="uploadProgressTextView"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_below="@+id/progressTextView"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:singleLine="false" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Continue"
        android:id="@+id/continueButton"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:onClick="continueButtonClick"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:height="48dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks for any advise :-)

Comment: Your LinearLayouts height is set to fill_parent so when you add layout_above to the ImageView it gets pushed just above the top of the screen. Change the LinearLayouts height to wrap_content and add the layout_above to the ImageView

Comment: Thanks! The image no longer overlaps my text and grows/shrinks as space is available. Unfortunately, the LinearLayout now gets pushed down by the ImageView (which is especially noticeable in portrait), even though the image is not so large that it would be necessary. Adding `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` to the LinearLayout did not help.

Comment: Do what I said before and change the height of the image view to match parent, that should make it only take the space that is available above the linearlayout (haven't tested but I think that should work)

Comment: Yes, it does take the rest of the place and that is the problem :-)
I want it to just match the size of the image that is displayed in there. The image displayed in the ImageView does have the correct dimensions, but as the ImageView is large than necessary, it is visually centered between the top of the screen (where it should be) and the top of the LinearLayout containing my TextViews.